# Complete uninstall of ubuntu 18.04 before reinstalling 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2

I've run into some issues on Ubuntu 18.04 dual-boot when trying to install some gpu drivers and I wanted to get a clean reinstall of Ubuntu 20.04. I formated the partitions on which Ubuntu was installed via diskmgmt.msc on Windows 10 but ubuntu still appears in the boot menu and i get into GNU Grub bash-like terminal when trying to boot into it. How to completely wipe Ubuntu 18.04 before installing the newest version ?

Comment: I think you have already removed Ubuntu, but there is still a menuentry for it in the [grub] boot menu. You need not worry about that. Go ahead and install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest would have been to run the installer from the live USB of Ubuntu 20.04. There is an option to replace an existing instance of Ubuntu.

If you do not see that option, then the easiest may be to delete the Ubuntu partition altogether using the Windows tools. Then, in the installer, you can choose to use the available space. The installer then automatically will create the partition for the new installation in the empty space.

In all cases, the Grub menu will be updated automatically based on the operating systems found on the disk after installing Ubuntu 20.04. So the old version of Ubuntu will be removed from the boot menu.